# Can't read private key DEPMOD

Tags: 12.04, kernel

I am a brand new user of Ubuntu 12.04. I have never used Linux. I am attempting to install CDEmu, but I am running into a problem.

I have downloaded the files and extracted them to a folder on my desktop. I open a terminal and cd to the directory.

I then type `sudo make`, it asks me for my user account password, I enter it then it seems to proceed:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-17-generic/build M=/home/family/Desktop/vhba-module-20130607 modules
make[1]: Entering directory /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic
CC [M]  /home/family/Desktop/vhba-module-20130607/vhba.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC      /home/family/Desktop/vhba-module-20130607/vhba.mod.o
LD [M]  /home/family/Desktop/vhba-module-20130607/vhba.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic
```

I then type `sudo make install`, and I get this:

```
family@ubuntu:~/Desktop/vhba-module-20130607$ sudo make install
make -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-17-generic/build M=/home/family/Desktop/vhba-module-20130607 modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic
INSTALL /home/family/Desktop/vhba-module-20130607/vhba.ko
Can't read private key
DEPMOD  3.11.0-17-generic
make[1]: Leaving directory /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I did some research that may help.

There is a [PPA for CDEmu](https://launchpad.net/~cdemu/+archive/ppa%E2%80%8E). See [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

So you don't need to compile/install it manually. Just open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and use

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cdemu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcdemu
```

Hope that help.

Here is the [instruction on German](http://linuxwelt.blogspot.ru/2013/09/ubuntu-1310-cdemu-daemon-tools.html), but it is simple to understand.